# How do I keep an OleDbConnection from trying to enlist in a distributed transaction?

Tags: .net, transactions, oledb

I am using OleDB to connect to an excel file using this connection string

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"""
```

But when I do this (which is inside a TransactionScope())

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    ...
}
```

I get the following error

> The ITransactionLocal interface is not
>   supported by the
>   'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider. 
>   Local transactions are unavailable
>   with the current provider.

How do I make the OleDbConnection not try to enlist in the distributed transaction? The [SqlConnection class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring.aspx) has a ConnectionString property called 'Enlist', but I can't find an equivalent configuration or method for OleDB.

Comment: But this is a local transaction right? The error is talking about local one only and not distributed one. I am not sure about your case but may be my post here [http://faiz.kera.la/2009/08/26/ssis-transaction-enabled-tasks-fail-due-to-msdtc] may help you.

Comment: yes, the error says local transaction, but there is not an explicit local transaction, just the TransactionScope

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In your connection string add the following code :
";OLE DB Services=-4;"

Comment: This is a fantastic solution that saved my bacon too! I hate how this stuff is so undocumented ... I'd like to know how you know it Reza?

Comment: I know this is 3 years old, but I stumbled upon this solution and wondered what's behind it. It disables ole db pooling and auto-enlistment. More information here, in Table 4: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810829.aspx