TransactionScope "A root ambient transaction was completed before the nested transaction"
Here's my scenario:
I have an extremely large table in Microsoft Access that I need to move to SQL Server.

public async Task Sync()
{
    using TransactionScope trans = new(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions()
    {
        IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted,
        Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
    }, TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled);
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<FlushpanelContext>()
        .UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CS") ?? throw new Exception("CS envar not defined"))
        .Options;
    await using var context = new FlushpanelContext(options
    );
    context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    await context.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();
    try
    {
        await using OleDbConnection mydb1 = new($@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={its2000Path};");
        await mydb1.OpenAsync();

        var partsService = new AccessPartsService(context, its2000Cn, logger);
        await partsService.SyncPartsAsync();
        trans.Complete();
    }
    finally
    {
        await context.Database.CloseConnectionAsync();
    }
}

public async Task SyncPartsAsync()
{
    // Get all of the parts from access
    var accessParts = await accessCn.QueryAsync<Access.Models.Part>("SELECT * FROM parts WHERE Imported = 0");
    logger.WriteLine($"{accessParts.Count()} parts to be imported in access", Color.DarkBlue);
    var partTypes = await context.PartType
        .Where(x => x.AccessTableId != null && x.AccessId != null)
        .ToDictionaryAsync(x => (x.AccessTableId!.Value, x.AccessId!.Value));
    var tablePartTypes = await context.PartType.Where(x => x.AccessTableId == null && x.AccessId == null)
        .ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Title);
    await ProcessBatch(accessParts, alreadyExistingSqlParts, manufacturers, partTypes, tablePartTypes);
    logger.WriteLine("Saving changes", Color.Purple);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    await accessCn.ExecuteAsync("UPDATE parts SET Imported = 1 WHERE Imported = 0");
    //await transaction.CommitAsync();
}

private async Task ProcessBatch(IEnumerable<Access.Models.Part> accessParts, Dictionary<string, int> alreadyExistingSqlParts, FrozenDictionary<string, int> manufacturers,
    Dictionary<(int accessTableId, int accessId), PartType> partTypes, Dictionary<string, PartType> tablePartTypes)
{
    // This will run for about 300,000 parts
    foreach (var accessPart in accessParts)
    {
            var converted = accessPart.ToPart(manufacturers);
            context.Part.Add(converted);
            logger.WriteLine($"Added part {accessPart.Part_ID}", Color.DarkGreen);
    }
}

I'm importing about 300,000 parts. This code runs fine if I only import 1000 records. However, if I try doing it all, I get the following error on await context.SaveChangesAsync(). I've tried putting the SaveChanges into the foreach, but the same issue arises near the end... Super weird and frustrating as this takes ~20 minutes to complete so it feels impossible to debug:
TransactionScope "A root ambient transaction was completed before the nested transaction"

I've set large timeouts, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

Why are you using efcore? is this an ongoing transfer? You can import access data using the import wizard in SSMS or probably even bulk import / openquery

@siggemannen This will run daily on a local server

Pretty sure you can do a sql server agent job that does: insert into ... select * from openquery / openrowset and updates the access table.

@300,000 doesn't qualify as extremely large

Could it be that your OleDB connection gets added to the transaction? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545064/how-do-i-keep-an-oledbconnection-from-trying-to-enlist-in-a-distributed-transact)

@Alex But that's the goal! Otherwise I'd be able to just do context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync(). But I want the transaction to be across both databases!

Why do you need to include Access database in the transaction? BTW these kinds of exercises are better done at the DB level (either OPENROWSET or SSIS). At the very least performance will be much faster.

@Alex because I'm setting the "imported" column to be set to TRUE, which actually isn't that crucial in this situation to be in the transaction. I moved to just use a single transaction from EFCore, but I'm also probably just going to move away from EF in the first place since it's too slow

Did not dig any deeper and second other comments telling you that this might be the wrong approach at all. Just a quick idea: You are changing the Imported flag which is the filter flag for your approach. If this is not performed after the other part it might block.  You might try IsolationLevel.Snapshot or .Serializable. This would at least prevent updates on the flag while still reading depending on the flag.

Do not use EF to perform bulk inserts it is not designed and suitable for such tasks. If you still want to use it - perform work in small batches (test your concrete scenario, I would start with ~1k) and  clear the change tracker/recreate the context. Alternatively look into things like SqlBulkCopy (be sure to check if it supports transactions).

"A root ambient transaction was completed before the nested transaction," typically occurs when there's an issue with transaction management. In your code, you're using both TransactionScope and Entity Framework's SaveChangesAsync, which might be causing conflicts.
Try using only one transaction management, Entity Framework Core (EF Core) can handles transactions internally, so using TransactionScope explicitly might interfere with its behavior.
Can you try removing the using TransactionScope and use the DbContext transaction management like so:
public async Task Sync()
{
    var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<FlushpanelContext>()
        .UseSqlServer(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CS") ?? throw new Exception("CS envar not defined"))
        .Options;
    await using var context = new FlushpanelContext(options
    );
    context.Database.SetCommandTimeout(TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
    await context.Database.OpenConnectionAsync();
    try
    {
        //
        //Create Transaction with EF
        using var trans = await context.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
        //

        await using OleDbConnection mydb1 = new($@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={its2000Path};");
        await mydb1.OpenAsync();

        var partsService = new AccessPartsService(context, its2000Cn, logger);
        await partsService.SyncPartsAsync();

        //
        //Commit Transaction with EF
        await trans.CommitAsync();
        //
    }
    finally
    {
        await context.Database.CloseConnectionAsync();
    }
}

